# Unity crashes after random if statement

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make some code that randomises my unity game's levels. This method is supposed to make a square filled with enemies. The IsPowered boolean randomly decides if a cloumn should be moving verticaly or not:

```
void Square(GameObject ship, float dY, float dX, float h, float w)
    {
        int i, j;
        bool IsPowered = false;
        float X = 2 + Camera.transform.position.x, speed = Random.Range(50.0f, 100.0f);

        //set position
        float Y = h / 2 * dY + dY / 2;
        for (j = 1; j <= w; j++)
        {
            IsPowered = false;
            if(Random.Range(0, 1) == 1)
                IsPowered = true;

            for (i = 1; i <= h; i++)
            {
                //makes ship
                temp = Instantiate(ship);
                if(IsPowered)
                {
                    if(Random.Range(0, 1) == 1)
                        speed = -speed;
                    temp.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, speed));
                }
                temp.transform.position = new Vector3(X + j * dX, Y - i * dY, 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that if the first Random.Range(0, 1) statement is true unity freezes. Btw I checked and if I remove the statment or make is always be true this doesn't happen.
Square being called:

```
void LateUpdate()
    {
        //if the player has moved 2 tiles then strat  a fight
        curentX = Camera.transform.position.x;
        if(Mathf.Abs(lastX - curentX) >= 10 && Mathf.Abs(curentX - 60) >= 8)
        {
            lastX = curentX;
            InBattle = true;
            //!Arguments: 0 - square, 1 - triangle, 2 - circle, 3 - bounce;
            CallRandom(0);
        }

        //if player has defeated all enemies exits battle mode
        EnemiesOnBoard = GameObject.FindWithTag("Enemy");
        if(EnemiesOnBoard == null && InBattle)
        {
            InBattle = false;
        }
    }
```

CallRandom method:

```
   void CallRandom(float nb)
    {
        float dY, h, dX, w;
        int nb2;
        switch (nb)
        {
            //sets up random stuff for square type of formation
            case 0:
                //randomises vertical stuff
                dY = Random.Range(1.0f, 2.0f);
                h = Random.Range(2, 4);
                while(h / 2 * dY + dY / 2 >= 4)
                    dY -= 0.1f;

                //randomizez horizontal stuff
                dX = Random.Range(1.0f, 2.0f);
                w = Random.Range(2, 4);
                while(w * dX > 5);
                    dX -= 0.1f;
                
                Square(EType0, dY, dX, h, w);
                break;
            //makes random triagnle type formation
            case 1:
                //vertical
                dY = Random.Range(1.0f, 2.0f);
                h = Random.Range(2.0f, 5.0f);
                while(h / 2 * dY + dY / 2  >= 4)
                    dY -= 0.1f;

                //horizontal
                dX = Random.Range(1.0f, 3.0f);
                while(dX * h >= 5)
                    dX -= 0.1f;

                Triangle(EType0, dY, dX, h);
                break;
            //makes random circle type fromation
            case 2:
                nb2 = Random.Range(4, 9);
                Circle(EType0, nb2);
                break;
            //makes random bouncie formation
            case 3:
                nb2 = Random.Range(5, 12);
                Bounce(EType0, nb2);
                break;
            default: 
                print("Something aint right");
                break;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I did some more testing and the problem seems to originate from one or both of the while loop in case 0 of the CallRandom method and it doesn't seem to happen enywhere else. Still don't know why is doesn't work

EDIT: I finally found the problem, and I actually hate myself now. The second while loop in case 0 of CallRandom had a ";" at the end of it so it created an infinite loop!

Comment: How can `Random.range(0, 1) == 1` be true? The upper range is exclusive.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html

Comment: Crashes?  Can you show how `Square()` is being called please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that there appears to be a direct link with frame updating (specifically `LateUpdate()`) and spawning new pre-fabs attached to new `GameObject`s. Our focus here isn't so much the prefabs but rather the `GameObject`s. `GameObject`s are a kinda expensive and there appears to be an upper limit you can have at one time per scene.<sup>[1]</sup><sup>[2]</sup>

Now `LateUpdate` is called *every* frame and let's say your game is running at *60 frames/second* (FPS).  So worst case is that you might be spawning **60 `GameObject`s/second**.  Unless you have coded some sort of lifetime management, you might be reaching Unity's limit causing it to crash.

### Thar be dragons

It's actually a little worse.  `LateUpdate()` (remember 60 FPS in our example) calls `CallRandom()` which calls `Square()` which living up to it's name isn't limited to spawning a single `GameObject` but a *square* of them with your nested loops of `w * h`.  Backtracking to `CallRandom()` we see that `w` and `h` could be anything up to `4` in value.

So:

```
<frame-rate> x 4 x 4 = <spawn-rate>

...or: 

60 x 4 x 4 = 960 game objects/sec
```

With some reports of the upper limit of GameObjects to be ~5,000, you would exceed that in approximately 5.2 seconds! <sup>[1]</sup><sup>[2]</sup>

### The fix

You have a few choices:

1. if you plan on spawning say 960 objects/sec you will need to delete older objects as you go.  Think of the famous Snake game
2. consider restructuring your visuals so that you need less `GameObject`s. e.g. Unity's Particle System works by having a single `GameObject` and component yet it can render 1,000s of particles effortlessly

---

1 https://answers.unity.com/questions/408298/max-number-of-gameobjects-5000-1.html

2 https://answers.unity.com/questions/365552/why-would-you-use-a-scriptable-object-versus-an-em.html

Comment: the problem is that I am not calling the function every frame but only once, when the player enters "Battle mode", basically when it goes forward with 8 units.